# When you implement an interface in Java is it explicit or implicit?

Tags: java, .net, interface

I just started figuring out the difference between implicit and explicit interface implmentation in .Net. Since I come from a Java background the idea is still a bit confusing. I am hoping knowing which Java does will make it more obvious what the difference is. I am assuming the Java is explicit???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope Java is implicit.  Explicit is where you are implementing multiple interfaces that have the same method signatures in them and you **explicitly** state which interface the implementation is for.

An example from MSDN:

```
public class SampleClass : IControl, ISurface
{
    void IControl.Paint()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("IControl.Paint");
    }
    void ISurface.Paint()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("ISurface.Paint");
    }
}
```

Here we have two `Paint()` methods, one from each interface.  In Java you can only have **one** Paint() implementation.  In C# you have the *option* of implementing versions for each interface so you get different behaviour depending how the class is called.

So if I called:

```
SampleClass c = new SampleClass();
((IControl)c).Paint();
((ISurface)c).Paint();
```

I'd get "IControl.Paint" printed out followed by "ISurface.Paint" printed out.

Comment: Okay that makes sense I guess. In Java I would just create a new interface to get around this problem.

Comment: Maybe another question then. I am trying to create an implementation of IDictionary(Of TKey, TValue). Are you saying that I should explicit implement all the IDictionary and rather implicit implement the others that come from ICollection and IEnumerable?

Comment: Generally the answer is no, unless you *really* need to have different behaviours for the different interfaces (and there had better be a damn good for that reason too) I would avoid using the explicit style.  
IDictionary already extends ICollection and IEnumerable so you don't need to implement these separately, just implement IDictionary.

Answer (score 2):

In Java there is no distinction between explicit and implicit.  If you have two interfaces that both declare a method with the same signature, and a class that implements both interface, then a method in the class with the correct signature implements the method in BOTH interfaces.

Comment: Okay. Then you cannot cast to either of the interfaces and use that particular version of the method. The version that you have is the only version and satisfies both interfaces?